# How to find the parent page of a webpage

Tags: html

I have a webpage that it cannot be accessed through my website.

Say, my website is www.google.com and the webpage that I cannot access using the website is like www.google.com/iamaskingthis/asdasd. This webpage appears on the google results when I type its content, however there is nothing which sends me to that page on my website.

I've already tried analyzing the page source to find its parent location but I can't seem to find it. I want to delete that page, but since I cannot find it, I can't destroy it either.

Thank you

Comment: You want to find the pages that link to this page?

Comment: There's only one way to reach that page within the website; a button. Since I've lost that button, I cannot click on it, and as a result I can't get the page. All I want is the route to go to that page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a robots.txt file to prevent search engine bots from visiting a page, and thus not showing search results for it.

For example, you can create a robots.txt file in the root of your website and add the following content to it:

```
    User-agent: *
    Disallow: /mysecretpage.html
```

More details at: http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html

Answer (score 1):

There is no such concept as a 'parent page'. If you mean, by which link Google found the page, plese keep in mind, that it need not be under your control: If I put a link to `www.google.com/iamaskingthis/asdasd` on a page on **my** website and thegooglebat crawls it, it will know about it.

To make it short: There is no reliable way of hiding a page on a website. Use authentication, if you want to restrict access.

Comment: I mean, there's a button that I should click to go to my lost webpage on my website. Since I do not have that button on my website anymore, I cannot access to that page either. However it is still there.. When I type its url, it is still on my server. How can I delete it?

Answer (score 0):

Google will crawl the page even if the button is gone, as it already has the page stored in it's records.  The only way to disallow google crawling to it is either robots.txt or simply deleting it off the server (via FTP or your hostings control panel).